# Matlab - skeleton branches belonging to the same structure

Tags: matlab, image-processing

By using `bwmorph`, one can identify the branch points in a skeleton and by subtracting them from the skeleton image, the residual image is left with the different branches.

What is a good way to determine if two branches belong to the same structure? I was thinking of checking the angle of branches situated around the same branch point. What is a good way of implementing this?

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Image where branch points have been removed:
[image: Image where branch points have been removed]

Comment: Could you post the image?

Comment: @Lokesh A. R. - In the image you can see how what seems to be the same line are separated into different branches by the branch points (which has been removed).

Comment: what do you mean "belong to the same structure"? are you wondering whether the branches were originally connected? Do you need to resolve  lines that cross as two different lines?

Comment: @Jonas - I would like to group together the branches that were originally connected given that they belong to the same trajectory so to speak.

Comment: @Mykje: Could you post the original image also?

Comment: @Lokesh A. R.: I have added the original image that contains the branch points as well as branches.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the image with the connected branches, you can simply use `bwlabel` to create an image where the 1's are replaced with a number for the structure.

Then, pick any pixel of a disconnected branch, and look up the structure number at its corresponding location in the labeled image.

Comment: The problem is that also not interesting branches that have different trajectory will be connected in the original image, and as such will have the same label as the branches of interest. Using bwlabel on the image shown, my problem would be how to match the label before a branch point to that after the branch point in cases where the branches follow the same trajectory.